# How do I delete my Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, account-management, facebook-account

I don't trust Facebook's new privacy settings and have decided to delete my account, but I can't find the kill switch.

Does anyone know how I can delete my Facebook account?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

from [here](http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=16929680703Blockquote):

> Go here:
> http://www.facebook.com/help/delete_account
>
> Click "Delete My Account" and follow the instructions.
>
> Your account will be deactivated for two weeks, and if you DO NOT USE FACEBOOK IN ANY WAY during that period, your account is permanently deleted.

Answer (score 20):

Go to "Your Account".  Go to "Deactivate Account".

Facebook is a megalomaniac.  It will never ever ever EVER delete your profile.  If you decide ten years later to sign in, then it will still be there.  I'd erase my pictures from the site before deleting my account.

Actually, I just did last week.

Comment: Do you have proof to back up your statement that "It will never ever ever EVER delete your profile. If you decide ten years later to sign in, then it will still be there."

Comment: I'll let you know in 10 years.

Comment: Hah well... the proof that I have is that after a year of a deactivated previous account, the same sign in information registered me back into their system and my profile was salvaged as it was when I left it.  So.  Megalomaniac.  Yes.

Comment: @Stefan Just ask the Archive.org ;-)

Comment: @Ivo: archive.org says "We're sorry, access to http://www.facebook.com has been blocked by the site owner via robots.txt. "

Comment: It's been over ten years. Has anyone here tried to sign in again?

Comment: @matpie Any updates?

Comment: 13 years. We'll see. (-;

Answer (score 10):

It is not neccessary to go through the deactivation 2 week wait, you can delete your account directly at:

[www.facebook.com/help/delete_account](http://www.facebook.com/help/delete_account)

> If you do not think you will use Facebook again and would like your account deleted, we can take care of this for you. Keep in mind that you will not be able to reactivate your account or retrieve any of the content or information you have added.

Comment: Even though it says this, you have to read further:
`What happens when my account has a pending deletion request?` ... "Once you have submitted a request to permanently delete your account, no further action is required on your end. Our system delays the deletion process in case you change your mind and no longer want to permanently delete your account. Note that logging in to your account again will undo a pending deletion request."