# How do I delete or merge a Facebook account I no longer have email access to?

Tags: facebook, passwords, account-management

I set up a Facebook account with a school email address long ago, when only school email addresses were allowed.  I graduated and no longer have that email address, nor access to it.  I have *also forgotten my password to that Facebook account.*

**How do I delete/merge a Facebook account that:**

1. **I forgot the password to**
2. **No longer have access to the registered email address?**

When I try to recover the forgotten password, I no longer have access to the email address that the Facebook account sends the password reset link to.

I once tried emailing a Facebook Support on this, and they replied saying they would merge it with my existing account I have access to, but they never did.  Are accounts like these doomed to exist on Facebook forever?

Similar question was posted previously, but this is slightly different: [How Do I Delete my Facebook Account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-delete-my-facebook-account)

Comment: the short answer ... yes.

Comment: My brother had a similar issue and now he has two accounts. So yea it sucks.

Comment: I think you can not delete it. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook [does not support account merging](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=13589). You have to manually copy what you want from your old profile, and then delete it.

You should be able to regain access to old account via http://www.facebook.com/#!/help/contact.php?show_form=hack_nologin_access - I've never used this and I don't know what they procedure is however. I guess once you have convinced them your are who you say you are, they will change the account email address, which will let you reset the password as normal.