# Delete an old Facebook account

Tags: facebook, delete, account-management

Two years ago somebody made a fanpage for our company, but that person doesn't work here anymore. We don't have any login or password. We like to see that account be deleted, please.

Comment: This is not facebook support. Write them an officially-looking letter.

Comment: @Martin To which adress, i have to send a letter ? I can't find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a facebook page?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11138/how-to-delete-a-facebook-page)

Comment: @Eight - not quite a duplicate in that question the solution assumes you have access to the page, which isn't the case here.

Comment: See also http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12719/regaining-facebook-fan-page-administrative-rights and http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/how-do-i-delete-or-merge-a-facebook-account-i-no-longer-have-email-access-to

Comment: I still got no answer for this problem. And i dont know how to post a comment instead a answer.

Comment: On both this site and Stack Overflow, register your account with the same details

Comment: Thanks, but could somebody give a another answer? I really want it to deleted it.

Comment: Bryan - If you register you Stack Overflow account with the same OpenID as this account you'll be able to comment on your question as it will be returned to your ownership.

Answer (score 5):

You can ask the deletion of the page through the Notice of Intellectual Property Infringement (Non-Copyright Claim) form : https://www.facebook.com/legal/copyright.php?noncopyright_notice=1