# Can I merge two of my Facebook accounts into one?

Tags: facebook, account-management

I have two accounts on Facebook, can I merge them?

My Facebook account was locked due some explicit content (somebody hacked my account). So, I created a new account, but most of my friends are connected to the first account. In the meantime, I requested and followed the steps to recover my Facebook account. Now I have several different friends in both accounts.

Is there any means to merge my accounts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Facebook help center](https://www.facebook.com/help/203498356357867/) reports merging two Facebook accounts is not possible yet, but Facebook provides you with [merging duplicate pages](https://www.facebook.com/help/249601088403018) option:

> We don't currently offer a way to merge two accounts. Before you close any of your accounts:
>
> - Download the information you've added to the account you don't want to keep (messages, pictures, friends' Facebook URLs, etc.)
> - Add the account you're keeping as an admin for any Groups or Pages you manage
>
> Once you've moved all of your info onto a single account, please delete your duplicate account.

If you don't know how to delete your excess Facebook account see [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-delete-my-facebook-account) already asked on webapps.