# How do I know which apps and accounts are connected to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, account-management, facebook-account

[Deleting a Facebook account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22/180156) involves selecting "Delete My Account" following some instructions then not using Facebook in any way for two weeks.

To ensure that I do not use Facebook in anyway, I want to disconnect all applications and accounts that use Facebook.  Is there a feature on Facebook that tells you which accounts and applications are connected to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login your Facebook account. Go to Account Settings. On the left side bar click on 'Apps'. It will list all the apps and website which is associated with your Facebook account. You can remove any or all of them.